# Understand Kafka replication factor

Tags: apache-kafka

When we say a topic is created with a Replication factors = 3. Does this mean each partition will have total of 3 replicas - out of which 1 will be leader and 2 will be replicas?

Or does this mean that there will be 3 replicas on top of 1 leader replica and therefore totally 4 replicas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replication factor of 3 includes the leader itself and 2 followers. Think of that factor in a more mathematical way: 1 times 3 still results in 3.

Let me give an example. A topic created with 3 partitions, replication factor of 3 results in 9 replicas. Three of those nine are leaders, the other six will be followers.

Unfortunately I didn't find something about that in the official documentation of Apache Kafka. But you can find some more details here https://www.javatpoint.com/kafka-topic-replication

Answer (score 0):

> 3 replicas on top of 1 leader replica and therefore totally 4 replicas? **NO**

> When we say a topic is created with a Replication factors = 3. Does this mean each partition will have total of 3 replicas - out of which 1 will be leader and 2 will be replicas? **YES**

Figure shows a three-node cluster with broker 3 as its leader and broker 2 and broker 1 as its followers, using `kinaction_helloworld` as a topic that might have been created in this manner.

- Broker 3 holds the leader replica for partition 2. As the leader, broker 3 handles all of the reads and writes from external producers and consumers.
- It also handles requests it receives from broker 2 and broker 1 as they pull new mes- sages into their copies. The ISR list [3,2,1] includes the leader in the first position (3) and then the remaining followers (2,1), who stay current with their copies of the messages from the leader.
  [image]

### Let me show this in Action.

With one replication-factor

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic one-replicated-topic

bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic one-replicated-topic
```

This will give output as

```
Topic: one-replicated-topic PartitionCount: 3   ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
    Topic: one-replicated-topic Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
    Topic: one-replicated-topic Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
    Topic: one-replicated-topic Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

---

With three replication-factor

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic three-replicated-topic


bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic three-replicated-topic
```

This gives the output as

```
Topic: three-replicated-topic   PartitionCount: 3   ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
    Topic: three-replicated-topic   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1,0 Isr: 2,1,0
    Topic: three-replicated-topic   Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,0,2 Isr: 1,0,2
    Topic: three-replicated-topic   Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,2,1 Isr: 0,2,1
```

> In Summary
> **Number of Partitions (3) x Replication Factor (3) = Total Replicas Created (9)**